# lucene 5.1.0 delete document from index with specific id

Tags: java, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I'm using Lucene 5.1.0 to index a document and search it.  I have a lot of documents, over 1000000, which are stored in a database.  When I start running the project for the first time, I use Lucene to index these documents.  Now I want to delete one document from the database and indexes.  I also choose an id for each index.  I am using the following command to delete, but it's delete all index.

```
iw.deleteDocuments(new Term("id", doc.id));
```

Also, I used a Query to delete but it's delete all index.

I add documents to the index as follows:

```
iDoc = new org.apache.lucene.document.Document();
FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();                        
fieldType.setIndexOptions(
IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
fieldType.setTokenized(true);
fieldType.setStored(true);
fieldType.setOmitNorms(true);
fieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);
fieldType.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPayloads(true);
fieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
iDoc.add(new Field("id", doc.id.toString(), fieldType));
iw.addDocument(iDoc);
```

Comment: How do you index your ID field?

Comment: Is it possible that you analyze you id in a way, it cant be found by the term you are using to delete it?

Comment: when i using search for specific id i able to find document but i just have problem in deleting it